# How can a man who already fulfilled his obligation of meggilla be yoetze a woman who has not?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory

According to the Noda Biyehuda a there is no areivus for women, meaning if a man fulfilled his obligation he won't be able to be yoetza her. I heard the minhag is for men who have already listened to the megilla to recite it for women. According to Rabbi Akiva Eiger women are included in areivus, however it should at least be a safek. For women meggilla is rabbinic. Are we relying on safek dirabanana likula? Or perhaps the obligation is to listen to the meggilla for women and no need for areivus?

Comment: MB 271:5 paskens like RAE (see shaar hatziyun 9). Also, even Dagul Merevava is not sure whether the only problem is a woman being motzi a man, or even the other way round like in your case

Comment: @joel kThanks you